# Aws Route53 setup for letsencrypt certificate with multiple subdomains and dns-01 challenge

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt

i am generating letsencrypt certificate using dehydrated(letsencrypt.sh) client and using dns-01 challenge for aws route53.

i have to generate single certificate for my following main and subdomains.

```
example.org qa01.example.org qa02.example.org
```

Here, example.org is just the public hosted zone and qa01.example.org and qa02.example.org are two apps running inside EC2 instances. These two apps are again under haproxy, namely proxy01.example.org.

Initially i had only one public hosted zone in Route53 namely 'example.org' that had CNAME created as follows:

```
qa01.example.org CNAME proxy01.example.org
qa02.example.org CNAME proxy01.example.org
```

and haproxy.cfg has appropriate config to redirect qa01 and qa02 url to appropriate ip addresses.

currently issue is that certificate is not generating for the subdomains. letsencrypt.sh throws error as **"zones qa01.example.org and qa02.example.org are not available"**.

should i create new public zones for qa01.example.org and qa02.example.org (and for any new apps i am spinning up in future like qa03.example.org etc)?

for testing purpose (as i am not sure if its proper solution) created **qa01.example.org and qa02.example.org public zones** in route53 and tried to run letsencrypt.sh, now it throws error as:

```
ERROR: Challenge is invalid! (returned: invalid) (result: {
  "type": "dns-01",
  "status": "invalid",
  "error": {
    "type": "urn:acme:error:connection",
    "detail": "DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.qa01.example.org",
    "status": 400
  }
```

How do i resolve this issue and is it possible to configure route53 so that certificate can be recreated for all the future subdomains without creating hosted zone for each subdomain.?

Comment: There is no need for additional hosted zones, and this would not really help you solve the fundamental problem here... particularly not unless you know exactly how to properly implement and delegate a zone cut in Route 53.  The fundamental issue is this: `NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.qa01.example.org`.  Do you in fact have a `TXT` record for `_acme-challenge.qa01.example.org`?  If not, why not? If so, change `qa01.example.org` from a `CNAME` to an `A` record, choose "Yes" next to "Alias," and select `example.org` as the alias target.

Comment: It seems intuitively wrong to expect `y.x.example.com` to be valid and usable when `x.example.com` is a `CNAME`, though I am having difficulty citing an authoritative source for this assertion.  Still, that's exactly why Route 53 created A-record aliases -- they ultimately *appear* to work the same way many people use `CNAME` records, as you are, but are implemented differently, more correctly for that specific purpose, and are thus without some of the limitations inherent in `CNAME`.

Comment: i think you are asking me to create A alias for proxy server 'proxy01.example.org', because i cant create for just 'example.org', it throws error as 'alias target contains invalid value' but works when i added 'proxy01.example.org'. When i generate certificate with having A alias for proxy and removing 'qa01.mybahmni.org' public zone, letsencrypt throws error as 'unable to find matching zone' for 'qa01.mybahmni.org' but able to validate dns-01 challenge for 'mybahmni.org'.